How to Moq SqlConnection And SqlCommand in .Net Core
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(AppSetting.DefaultConnection))
{
    connection.Open();
 
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                string fieldValue = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? "" : reader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}

When I tried running this code for unit testing, it threw an error. Is there another approach I should consider for this?

Can you edit your question to include the error message
